# Redirect Loop on one page when using Custom Permalink in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, redirect, permalinks

I have a Wordpress site (nicee.co) and I've been using the plugin called custom Permalinks that lets me custom links for a year. This problem has never happened before but I was trying to rename the URL of a page (not post) and every browser I tested with says there's a redirect loop. Here's the link: www.nicee.co/guides/shopping/grocery

I can preview the page when I'm logged in to my site but if you access through the public URL it will say there's a redirect loop. Can anyone help me on this? I'd really appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its hard to troubleshoot issues like this, especially when it doesn't occur when you're logged in. However, it almost seems like you have a redirect for 'guides/shopping/grocery' pointing to '/guides/shopping/grocery/' and vice versa - so the redirect is just bouncing back and forth.

Comment: Thank you. I unchecked the "Enforce a trailing slash on all category and tag URL's" in Yoast SEO plugin and this problem went away.

Comment: Glad it helped! If you think this was the correct answer, please select it as so. This will also make people more willing to answer your future questions.